# Insert value of hidden input along with select <option>

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert a hidden value into the DB if I selected the first option the hidden value should be inserted into the different column.

So this is my code :

```
    <select class="form-control" id="students" name="students" size="1" required>
     <option dir='rtl'value=''>choose a course :)</option>
    <?php


    $query = "SELECT gid,course_id,course_title,course_cord,group_time,course FROM courses JOIN groups WHERE course_id = course ORDER BY gid DESC ";
    $run = $connection->prepare($query);
    if(!$run){

    die("ded !".mysqli_error($connection));
    }
    $run->execute();
    $run->bind_result($gid,$course_id,$course_title,$course_cord,$group_time,$course);


    while($run->fetch()):



     echo "<option dir='rtl'value='$course_id'>($group_time)$course_title BY $course_cord </option> ";
                    endwhile;

?>


     </select>
```

my hidden input :

```
<?php


           $query2 = "SELECT gid,course_id,course_title,course_cord,group_time,course FROM courses JOIN groups WHERE course_id = course ";
            $run2 = $connection->prepare($query2);
            if(!$run2){

              die("rip".mysqli_error($connection));
            }
            $run2->execute();
            $run2->bind_result($gid,$course_id,$course_title,$course_cord,$group_time,$course);

           while($run2->fetch()):

 ?>

<input type='hidden' id='hiddenInput' name='group_id' value='<?php echo $gid; >'>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Every `<option>` has a value of $gid.

Like this :

[image: Screen shot]

so if I selected course 6 it should `insert` in `group_id` column value of 31

For now, it is inserting only the first hidden input even if I choose the course 5

Is it possible to do it with PHP only? because I don't much about jQuery and stuff.

I'm still a beginner.

**EDIT**:

my insert query :

```
    $statement = $connection->prepare("
            INSERT INTO students (name_student,students,specialization,phone_num,paid,chair,group_id)
            VALUES (:name_student,:students,:specialization,:phone_num,:paid,:chair,:group_id)
        ");

        $result = $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':name_student' =>  $_POST["name_student"],
                ':students' =>  $_POST["students"],
                ':specialization'   =>  $_POST["specialization"],
                ':phone_num'    =>  $_POST["phone_num"],
                ':chair'    =>  "1",
                ':paid' =>  $_POST["paid"],
                ':group_id' =>  $_POST['group_id']


)
        );
```

Comment: Where are the hidden inputs coming from?

Comment: @Phil I updated my question

Comment: You could always make the `<option>` value something like `value='$course_id:$gid'` and use `list($course_id, $gid) = explode(':', $_POST['students']);` on the backend

Comment: you use the same id\name twice in your inputs

Comment: @Phil I tried to use your code but I get in group_id column  this value :[screenshot](http://prntscr.com/jfibjx])

Comment: So, PHP is a pre- hypertext processor.. that means it does all of its rendering and code before it sends it to the user.. if you want to interact with the database, you will need to combine an AJAX or jQuery script wit a PHP script together  using $.post() or something

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: @mike510a that sounds like a terrible idea. Why would OP need to use AJAX at htis point?

Comment: because the OP said this:  "so if I selected course 6 it should insert in group_id column value of 31"

Comment: @MRDV what **exactly** did you use? If you used `list` like in my example, you shouldn't get an array

Comment: @mike510a OP just wants to use the selected option to refer to two values, course and group ID

Comment: @Phil ':group_id' => list($course_id, $gid) = explode(':',$_POST['students']);
 is it gonna be like this ?

Comment: I see whatt the OP is asking

Comment: @Phil oh okay I get it now .. but I get an error when I put list($course_id, $group_id) = explode(':', $_POST['students']); inside the array

Comment: What error? What do you mean by _"inside the array"_?

Comment: @Phil Never mind .. I made a stupid mistake .. now its working like a charm :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to use one control to submit multiple values. One of the simplist is to create a formatted string with a delimter.

For example

```
<option value='$course_id:$gid'...
```

Then when you handle the form submit, you can split (`explode()`) the value to get the parts, eg

```
list($course_id, $group_id) = explode(':', $_POST['students']);
```

This will assign values to those two variables which you can then bind into your query, eg

```
':group_id' => $group_id,
':students' => $course_id
```

Using this, you won't need the hidden inputs which saves you having to execute the query a second time.

Comment: thank you so much ! But one thing ! I'm using ajax to submit my form and insert the value, but when I edited the student I don't see the value as selected the output is like this: $output["students"] = $row["students"];
Do I use explode again?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean and you seem to have omitted **vital** information from your original question

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to do this:  just add a few more  properties to the hidden elements and to the options so that they can find each other... kind of like this:

```
<input type='hidden' id='hiddenInput' name='group_id' value='<?php echo $gid; >' course_id='<?php echo $course_id?>' >
```

SO that the resulting outpout is

Then you can just grab that group ID of any option value by doing

```
var element =  document.querySelector("#students");
var courseId = element.value
var selector = 'input[course_id=' + courseId + ']'
var hiddenElement =  document.querySelector(selector)
var GID = hiddenElement.value
alert("You picked course: " + courseId + " which is group: " + GID);
```